# Could not locate plugin Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Indexing@5.2.113. Some CLI commands may not function correctly

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

While implementing Sitecore Content Serialization using Sitecore Cli, getting this error:

```
"Could not locate plugin Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization@5.2.113. Some CLI commands may not function correctly."

"Could not locate plugin Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Indexing@5.2.113. Some CLI commands may not function correctly."

"Could not locate plugin Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.ResourcePackage@5.2.113. Some CLI commands may not function correctly."

"Could not locate plugin Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Database@5.2.113. Some CLI commands may not function correctly."
```

[image]

I have checked and updated the version of plugins using the following commands to 5.2.113:

```
dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Serialization --version {version}
dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Publishing --version {version}
dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.Indexing --version {version}
dotnet sitecore plugin add -n Sitecore.DevEx.Extensibility.ResourcePackage --version {version}
```

[image]

but still getting this error message in powershell terminal.
I am unable to find the reason why Sitecore CLI keep complaining that a plugin can't be located when it is infact installed in "`..\Serialization\.sitecore\package-cache\nuget`" folder.

Comment: Kindly add error in text rather than image for SEO purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar problem while doing CLI setup in Sitecore 10.1. After discussing with Sitecore support, I removed the CLI plugins from my project and did the fresh CLI installation again. That fixed my problem.
You can also try this once.